# Automatic image resizing if browser width = 

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoresize

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801102/using-jquery-javascript-to-create-a-dynamic-image-what-am-i-doing-wrong) today and got some great answers (thanks to the guys who helped me out there :) ).

Now please have a look at the following code. I'm a 100% sure the resizing part works, but my if/else statement doens't work (I'm still a JS rookie). I also mentioned this in my previous topic, but someone said I should rather post a new question.

(The script should detect someones browser width, so it can resize the #fluidimage)
note: the resizing part works. Only the viewportwidth detection and the if/else statement isnt functional yet.

```
$(window).load ( function () {

    function resizer (index, measurement) {
        var imageresize = 80;
        var viewportWidth = width();

       if ((viewportWidth >= 1680)) {
            imageresize = 100;
       } else if ((viewportWidth <= 1680) && (viewportWidth > 1280)) {
            imageresize = 80;
       } else if ((viewportWidth <= 1280) &&  (viewportWidth > 1024)) {
            imageresize = 60;
       } else if ((viewportWidth <= 1024) ) {
            imageresize = 40;
       } else {
            imageresize = 100;
       }


        this.wCall = (typeof this.wCall == "null") ? true : this.wCall ^ true;
        return this.wCall ? Math.round (measurement * imageresize / 100) : measurement;
    }
    $("#fluidimage").width (resizer).height (resizer);
} );
```

Comment: Would you consider doing the sizing in pure CSS? You could follow the width-logic in a framework such as Less Framework (http://lessframework.com/) and then you'd be able to avoid any flicker effect between when the image has loaded and when the DOM is finished rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
var viewportWidth = width();
```

To:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
```

[See it at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/U9fyH/5/)